# Find the nearest data about one minute ago in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to find the nearest data point around one minute before the current data point in a for-loop.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
    Timestamp               Value
36  2000-11-08 23:30:40.370 45.5
47  2000-11-13 04:52:29.410 44.5
67  2000-12-01 22:17:50.300 42.5
129 2000-11-24 00:57:11.950 43.0
176 2000-12-03 01:40:16.250 42.0
246 2000-11-12 07:32:54.000 43.5
281 2000-11-30 21:13:07.630 45.5
335 2000-11-30 20:43:11.050 43.5
```

The for-loop looks like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(df.index)-1):

    if some_condition: 
        
        current_data_time = df.loc[i, "Timestamp"] 
        
        one_min_ago = df.loc[i, 'Timestamp'] - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 1)
    
        nearest_data_one_minute_ago = df.loc[["Timestamp"] == one_min_ago, "Value"]
```

How do I find `nearest_data_one_minute_ago` , if there is not a value at exactly `one_min_ago`?

---

Edit:

Expected output:

```
    Timestamp               Value   nearest_data_one_minute_ago
36  2000-11-08 23:30:40.370 45.5    NaN
47  2000-11-13 04:52:29.410 44.5    (should be `Value` at `2000-11-13 04:51:29.410`, if there isn't, find the nearest, before or after doesn't matter)
67  2000-12-01 22:17:50.300 42.5    (should be `Value` at `2000-12-01 22:16:50.300`, if there isn't, find the nearest, ...)
129 2000-11-24 00:57:11.950 43.0    (should be `Value` at `2000-11-24 00:56:11.950`, if there isn't, find the nearest, ...)
176 2000-12-03 01:40:16.250 42.0    (should be `Value` at `2000-12-03 01:39:16.250`, if there isn't, find the nearest, ...)
246 2000-11-12 07:32:54.000 43.5    (should be `Value` at `2000-11-12 07:31:54.000`, if there isn't, find the nearest, ...)
281 2000-11-30 21:13:07.630 45.5    (should be `Value` at `2000-11-30 21:12:07.630`, if there isn't, find the nearest, ...)
335 2000-11-30 20:43:11.050 43.5    (should be `Value` at `2000-11-30 20:42:11.050`, if there isn't, find the nearest, ...)
```

Please note that the sample data is just an example for data format where in reality there is more data with smaller time intervals.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: first off, why for loop. what is the input to check the nearest one minute? Are you looking to get the nearest one minute for each row in the dataframe? You need to be more clear for us to take this on. Always post expected answer so we know what you are looking for

Comment: Subtract the time you want to search for and sort by the `abs` of the difference. The closest time will have the smallest difference

Comment: @MayankPorwal Please see edited question.

Comment: Hi @JoeFerndz I need a for-loop as I have multiple other operations which I need to apply on the data, a for-loop would allow for the flexibility. Besides, the dataset is large and for-loop allows me to scan through the data once and apply all functions I need. I hope that makes sense

Comment: you can do `df.apply(your_own_function, axis=1)`, this will take all columns and pass it to the function. You can do whatever operation with it. Are you looking for a solution specifically to look for a one minute difference?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a simple sort by Timestamp, then get shift(-1) of Value?

Comment: Hi @JoeFerndz `apply` is a great idea, but what I'm gonna do is more trivial and complicated than one function, I'm not sure if I can wrap everything in one function that's why resorting to for-loop, which I thought would be more flexible, I might be wrong though.. I think I might try an `abs` of difference, as suggested by @Iain Shelvington

Comment: Here's the challenge. I saw your expected output. If the data from the previous row is not within the 1 minute window, then you want to pick the next best row. So if i have timestamp ends as follows `['04:52:29.410', 04:53:15.410',`04:56:25.410','04:58:25.410']`, then you will pick the Value from the immediate previous row. It does not matter if it is within the 1 minute window. So why not just do shift(-1)

Comment: @JoeFerndz it's because sometimes there are more data within `1min`, for example, current timestamp is `'04:52:29.410'` and we have following timestamp `['04:52:33.410', 04:52:35.410',04:52:40.410','04:52:44.410']`. Btw there was some typo in expected output where I mistook seconds for minute, I just fixed that.

Comment: if there are more data, you want to pick the smallest delta or all the values within the 1 min window?

Answer (score 3):

If need match by closest values to 1 minute is possible use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with same DataFrame with parameters `allow_exact_matches=False` for prevent matching same rows and `tolerance` for specify 1 minute:

```
print (df)
                   Timestamp  Value
36   2000-11-08 23:30:40.370   45.5
47   2000-11-08 23:30:29.410   44.5  <- change data for match
67   2000-12-01 22:17:50.300   42.5
129  2000-11-24 00:57:11.950   43.0
176  2000-12-03 01:40:16.250   42.0
246  2000-11-12 07:32:54.000   43.5
281  2000-11-30 21:13:07.630   45.5
335  2000-11-30 20:43:11.050   43.5

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

df = df.sort_values('Timestamp')

df = pd.merge_asof(df, df, 
                   on='Timestamp', 
                   allow_exact_matches=False,
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(1, 'min'))
print (df)
                Timestamp  Value_x  Value_y
0 2000-11-08 23:30:29.410     44.5      NaN
1 2000-11-08 23:30:40.370     45.5     44.5
2 2000-11-12 07:32:54.000     43.5      NaN
3 2000-11-24 00:57:11.950     43.0      NaN
4 2000-11-30 20:43:11.050     43.5      NaN
5 2000-11-30 21:13:07.630     45.5      NaN
6 2000-12-01 22:17:50.300     42.5      NaN
7 2000-12-03 01:40:16.250     42.0      NaN
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks for your answer. Is there a for-loop solution to do this? As I have other operations which I need to apply to the function, a for-loop would allow for that.

Comment: @nilsinelabore - hmmm, unfortunately  I have no idea how create  `merge_asof` in loops (with good performance). Btw,  what are another operation need in loop? Is possible be more specific? Because if need loops, why not first use `merge_asof` and then use loops? Not understand it.

Comment: So there are multiple other things I'd like to calculate. One of them is that I only need to find the `Value` nearest to 1 minutes ago if the `some_condition` in the for-loop qualifies the current data point as a "peak", which means that it is higher than both the value before and after itself. Besides, after finding the data point, say `point A` 1min ago, I also need to find the values in the range of +/-2min of `point A`, that's why I need the loop.

Comment: @nilsinelabore - Ok, unfortunately I have no idea for fast merge_asof in loop, so I cant help you  with it.

Comment: That's okay, thanks for your contributions anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for a for-loop solution. Here's something you can do without a for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c = ['Timestamp','Value']
d = [['2000-11-08 23:30:40.370', 45.5],
     ['2000-11-13 04:52:00.410', 31.5], #modified
     ['2000-11-13 04:52:15.410', 32.5], #modified 15 secs from 2000-11-13 04:52:00.410
     ['2000-11-13 04:52:30.410', 33.5], #modified 30 secs from 2000-11-13 04:52:00.410
     ['2000-11-13 04:52:45.410', 34.5], #modified 45 secs from 2000-11-13 04:52:00.410
     ['2000-11-13 04:53:00.410', 35.5], #modified  1  min from 2000-11-13 04:52:00.410
     ['2000-11-13 04:53:15.410', 36.5], #modified new set within 1 min of 2000-11-13 04:52:15.410
     ['2000-12-01 22:17:50.300', 42.5],
     ['2000-11-24 00:57:11.950', 43.0],
     ['2000-12-03 01:40:16.250', 42.0],
     ['2000-11-12 07:32:54.000', 43.5],
     ['2000-11-30 21:13:07.630', 45.5],
     ['2000-11-30 20:43:11.050', 43.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

#convert timestamp to datetime format
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

#sort dataframe by Timestamp
df = df.sort_values('Timestamp')

df['Diff_Next'] = ((pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'].shift(-1)) - pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])).dt.total_seconds() / 60)
df['Diff_Prev'] = df['Diff_Next'].shift(1)

df.loc[df['Diff_Next'] <= 1,'Nearest_Value'] = df.Value.shift(-1).fillna(0)
df.loc[df['Diff_Prev'] <= 1,'Nearest_Value'] = df.Value.shift(1).fillna(0)

print (df)
```

This will check if previous timestamp is within 1 min. If so, it will use that value else, it will look for next timestamp and if that's within 1 min, then it will use that value. If none, it will assign NaN.

I need to check for next before prev. That will ensure prev value takes precedence.

The output of the modified dataframe will be:

```
                 Timestamp  Value     Diff_Next     Diff_Prev  Nearrest_Value
0  2000-11-08 23:30:40.370   45.5   4802.227167           NaN             NaN
10 2000-11-12 07:32:54.000   43.5   1279.106833   4802.227167             NaN
1  2000-11-13 04:52:00.410   31.5      0.250000   1279.106833             NaN
2  2000-11-13 04:52:15.410   32.5      0.250000      0.250000            31.5
3  2000-11-13 04:52:30.410   33.5      0.250000      0.250000            32.5
4  2000-11-13 04:52:45.410   34.5      0.250000      0.250000            33.5
5  2000-11-13 04:53:00.410   35.5      0.250000      0.250000            34.5
6  2000-11-13 04:53:15.410   36.5  15603.942333      0.250000            35.5
8  2000-11-24 00:57:11.950   43.0   9825.985000  15603.942333             NaN
12 2000-11-30 20:43:11.050   43.5     29.943000   9825.985000             NaN
11 2000-11-30 21:13:07.630   45.5   1504.711167     29.943000             NaN
7  2000-12-01 22:17:50.300   42.5   1642.432500   1504.711167             NaN
9  2000-12-03 01:40:16.250   42.0           NaN   1642.432500             NaN
```

Note here that the values in `Diff_Prev` and `Diff_Next` is in whole number representation. So 0.25 is 15 min (quarter of a minute).

If you still want to iterate through the dataframe using loops, then use this solution. I strongly recommend NOT doing this.

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Diff_Prev'] <= 1:
        df.loc[i,'Nearrest_Value'] = df.loc[i-1,'Value']
    elif row['Diff_Prev'] <= 1:
        df.loc[i,'Nearrest_Value'] = df.loc[i+1,'Value']
```

You will get same results. The good part of this loop is that you don't have to worry about first row and last row. The NaN value in `Diff_Prev` and `Diff_Next` will resolve itself due to the `if` and `elif` statements.

Let me know if you are looking for the value that's closest to 1 min window between current row and any previous rows.

For example if the data is as shown below,

```
 ['2000-11-13 04:52:00.410', 44.5], 
 ['2000-11-13 04:52:15.410', 44.5], 
 ['2000-11-13 04:52:30.410', 44.5], 
 ['2000-11-13 04:52:45.410', 44.5], 
 ['2000-11-13 04:53:00.410', 44.5], 
 ['2000-11-13 04:53:15.410', 44.5],
```

Do you want `04:52:45` to be the closest 1 min difference to `04:52:00` and ignore other values like `04:52:15` and `04:52:30` ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution Joe. Yes I need the data closest to the 1 min gap time point, rather than any data that is within 1min time difference.

Comment: Ok. In that case I need to do a lookup. Will share updated code later tonight